# Какой язык будет выводить google в запросах?

Tags: php, google-search, google-translate

Мне просто интересно, каким образом google подставляет описания и ключевые слова.

К примеру, у меня есть многоязычный сайт написан на php. Есть кнопка выбор языка. Естественно в базе данных есть описания на всех языках, какой язык выбран на этом и выводит текст, если язык не выбран, то будет английский.

Вопрос: какой язык будет выводить google в запросах? И ещё один вопрос: стоит ли использовать скрипт google-переводчик сайтов?
Удобная штука, но правильно ли он переводит?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу языков - все есть в документации гугла по этому поводу [ссылка](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru)
Если кратно - используйте тег `hreflang`. По поводу скрипта-переводчика - переводит он вполне себе понятно, однако если выбор между ним и ручным переводом - я бы выбрал ручной, потому как гугл переводчик зачастую слова с двойным смыслом и некоторые языковые конструкции языка переводит не так, как хотелось бы, от чего смысл текста может очень сильно измениться